# Cannot implement Foldable instance due to wrong kind

Tags: haskell, ghc, foldable

I am learning haskell and trying to make a pretty print program. At some point I want to get the length of a row (i.e. number of columns in that row). To be able to do that on my datatype I understand I have to implement Foldable, which relies on Monoid.

Previously my row was just a type alias for a list but for sake of learning I want to make this move

```hs
    import System.IO
    import System.Directory
    import Control.Monad
    import Data.Maybe
    import Data.Monoid
    import Data.Foldable
    import Data.Functor
    import Data.List.Split

    type Field = String
    data Row = Row [Field]

    instance Monoid Row where
        mempty = Row []


    instance Foldable Row where
        foldMap f (Row fs) = foldMap f fs
```

But I get the following compiler error (on ghci 8.0.2)

```
main.hs:20:19: error:
    • Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘Row’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the first argument of ‘Foldable’, namely ‘Row’
      In the instance declaration for ‘Foldable Row’
```

Now I am not familiar with what the kind of a datatype is. I was expecting this to simply defer to Row's only property of type List

Answer (score 4):

When we have `Foldable T`, `T` must be a *parametric* type, i.e. we must be able to form types `T Int`, `T String`, etc.

In Haskell we write `T :: * -> *` for "a type parametrized over a type", since it resembles a function from types to types. The syntax `* -> *` is called the *kind* of `T`.

In your case, `Row` is not parametrized, it is a plain type, something of kind `*`, not `* -> *`. So, `Foldable Row` is a kind error. In a sense, a foldable must be a *generic* list-like container, not one that only carries `Field` as in your case.

You could instead define `data Row a = Row [a]`, and use `Row Field` when you need that specific case.

Alternatively, you could try `MonoFoldable Row` from the `mono-traversable` package, but note that this is a more advanced option, involving type families. Do not take this path lightly before considering its consequences. It ultimately boils down to *why* you need a `Foldable` instance.

Comment: @HugoPeters With the standard `length` from `Foldable` and non-parametrized `Row` it is indeed impossible. You can declare a different length function, but that will need to have another name (or be in another package, and disambiguate between the two length functions manually). For instance `MonoFoldable` provides `olength` to avoid the name clash.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the *"kind"* of a datatype?

Types "of kind `*`" are types of *things that can appear in a Haskell program*.

Example: `Int`.

Not an example: `Maybe`.

`a :: Int ; a = 1` can appear in a Haskell program but `b :: Maybe ; b = Just 1` can't. It must be `b :: Maybe Int ; b = Just 1`, to be valid for it to appear in a Haskell program.

What is `Maybe Int`? It is a type of kind `*` just as  `Int` is. So what is `Maybe`? It is a type of kind `* -> *`. Because *`Maybe Maybe`* is *also* invalid.

The type `t` appearing after the `Maybe` must itself be of kind `*` for `Maybe t` to be of kind `*`. Thus the kind of `Maybe` is `* -> *`.

Haskell now calls the kind `*` by new name, `Type`. Calling it `Thing` or something  could have been more intuitive.